# Extracting RGB data from bitmapData (NSBitmapImageRep) Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image-processing

I am working on an application which needs to compare two images, in order to see how different they are and the application does this repeatedly for different images. So the way I currently do this is by having both the images as `NSBitmapImageRep`, then using the `colorAtX: y:` function in order to get a `NSColor` object, and then examining the RGB components. But this approach is extremely slow. So researching around the internet I found posts saying that a better way would be to get the bitmap data, using the function bitmapData, which returns an unsigned char. Unfortunately for me I don't know how to progress further from here, and none of the posts I've found show you how to actually get the RGB components for each pixel from this `bitmapData`. So currently I have :

```
 NSBitmapImageRep* imageRep = [self screenShot]; //Takes a screenshot of the content displayed in the nswindow
unsigned char *data = [imageRep bitmapData]; //Get the bitmap data

//What do I do here in order to get the RGB components?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pointer you get back from `-bitmapData` points to the RGB pixel data. You have to query the image rep to see what format it's in. You can use the `-bitmapFormat` method which will tell you whether the data is alpha first or last (RGBA or ARGB), and whether the pixels are ints or floats. You need to check how many samples per pixel, etc. [Here are the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsbitmapimagerep_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSBitmapFormat). If you have more specific questions about the data format, post those questions and we can try to help answer them.

Usually the data will be non-planar, which means it's just interleaved RGBA (or ARGB) data. You can loop over it like this (assuming 8-bit per channel, 4 channels of data) :

```
int width = [imageRep pixelsWide];
int height = [imageRep pixelsHight];
int rowBytes = [imageRep bytesPerRow];
char* pixels = [imageRep bitmapData];
int row, col;
for (row = 0; row < height; row++)
{
    unsigned char* rowStart = (unsigned char*)(pixels + (row * rowBytes));
    unsigned char* nextChannel = rowStart;
    for (col = 0; col < width; col++)
    {
        unsigned char red, green, blue, alpha;

        red = *nextChannel;
        nextChannel++;
        green = *nextChannel;
        nextChannel++;
        // ...etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This method worked perfectly (with a few changes, like the name of the methods pixelWidth -> pixelsWide etc and also I assume you meant row < width in the outer loop). Also your hunch was right, the data was RGBA, 8-bit per channel and 4 channels of data.

Comment: Actually, the outer loop is correct, the inner loop is wrong. It should be `col < width`. I'll correct it.

Comment: Excellent! Extremely fast using pointers like this. Went from 500 seconds looping through a 20k pixels x 20k pixels using colorAt instances, to under 10 seconds using your code.

Comment: Super. I called `[imageRep bitmapFormat]` to check my bitmap format and had to remember to call `nextChannel++` exactly four times in the loop.